# How to change button icon when button is clicked in react.js

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a react function which returns a button.

```
<div className="col-6 btn-group btn-group w-100">
       <AuditMenuButtons buttonValue='Pending' buttonName='Inbox' changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_inbox}/>
       <AuditMenuButtons buttonValue='Rejected' buttonName='Rejected' changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_rejected}/>
       <AuditMenuButtons buttonValue='Accepted' buttonName='Accepted' changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_accepted}/>
</div>
```

Function is added below

```
    function AuditMenuButtons(props) {
    return(
        <button className="w-25 btn menu-btn p-lg-3" name={props.buttonName} value={props.buttonValue} onClick={props.changeFilterForButton}><img src={props.icon} className="pr-3 menu-btn-icons">
        </img>{props.buttonName}</button>
    );
}
```

You will see 3 buttons in above code. I want to change the button icon when one button is clicked. actually button icon color should be green when button is clicked. Images are .png file (with green and silver border). I tried button:active in css it didn't work for me. Image should remain until I clicked another button or page was refreshed

Comment: you want to change the icon or color? Do you mean you want to color to be green till the mouse is released? Please edit the question for clarity

Comment: can you be more clear in your question ?

Comment: @PraveenRaoChavan.G I want to change the color when button is clicked and it should remain until i click another button. I have two images, one with silver and one with green color.

Comment: @PubuduJayasanka I have edited my answer pls check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the **icon** part is a **UI state**, it has to maintained in your state and passed down to `AuditMenuButtons` has props.

> use these `props` in `AuditMenuButtons` to do the desired check.

```
        import React,{Component} from 'react';

        class demoComponent extends from Component{
            this.state={
               isClicked:false,
               buttonIcons:{
                  pending:{active_Icon:"../IconURL",Icon:"../IconURL"},
                  rejected:{active_Icon:"../IconURL",Icon:"../IconURL"},
                  accepted:{active_Icon:"../IconURL",Icon:"../IconURL"}
               }
            }

           clickHandler = (event) =>{
             this.setState(
              {
                isClicked:!this.state.isClicked // this is gonna toggle everytime you click //
              }
             );
           }

           render(){
              return <div className="col-6 btn-group btn-group w-100">
                     <AuditMenuButtons clickhandler={this.clickHandler} buttonValue='Pending' buttonName='Inbox' isClicked={this.state.isClicked} buttonIcons={this.state.buttonIcons} changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_inbox}/>
                     <AuditMenuButtons clickhandler={this.clickHandler} buttonValue='Rejected' buttonName='Rejected' isClicked={this.state.isClicked}  buttonIcons={this.state.buttonIcons} changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_rejected}/>
                     <AuditMenuButtons clickhandler={this.clickHandler} buttonValue='Accepted' buttonName='Accepted'  isClicked={this.state.isClicked} buttonIcons={this.state.buttonIcons} changeFilterForButton={this.props.changeFilterForButton} icon={icon_accepted}/>
              </div>
           }
        }

        export default demoComponent;
```

Comment: I could fix the issue from this. Not the same code actually.

Comment: Don't forget to vote the question if you think it is important

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this in your **.css** file.

```
.button:focus{background: url('your new green image');
```

Comment: Focus works only till the time the button is pressed. He wants to update the icon after click i.e after the mouse is released

Answer (score 0):

> You can manage the image path in react state and call a method attach
>   it to onClick, where you use setState() and update the state.

Refer
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
this.state = {
image_path: 'your image url here'
}

changeUrl = () => {
this.setState({image_path:'new path'});
}
<AuditMenuButtons onClick={this.changeUrl} src={this.state.image_path}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
changeFilterForButton: function (props) {
     props.currentTarget.style.backgroundColor = '#ccc';
}

function AuditMenuButtons(props) {
    return(
        <button className="w-25 btn menu-btn p-lg-3" name={this.props.buttonName} 
value={this.props.buttonValue} onClick={this.props.changeFilterForButton}><img src={this.props.icon} className="pr-3 menu-btn-icons">
        </img>{this.props.buttonName}</button>
    );
}
```

or if you want to use react methodology then you can use construtor like this

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isColor: false};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.changeFilterForButton= this.changeFilterForButton.bind(this);
  }

  changeFilterForButton() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isColor: !state.isColor
    }));
  }


  function AuditMenuButtons(props) {
    return (
<button className="w-25 btn menu-btn p-lg-3" name={props.buttonName} value={props.buttonValue} onClick={props.changeFilterForButton} style="background-color: {this.state.isColor? '#CCC' : ''} "><img src={props.icon} className="pr-3 menu-btn-icons">
    </img>{props.buttonName}</button>

    );
  }
```